# DataSet using first row as column header move the checkbox column 1 row down

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have DataSet which i populate from Excel file:

```
            OleDbConnection conn;
            OleDbDataAdapter command;

            conn = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + filePath + " ';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; ");
            conn.Open();

            firstSheetName = GetFirstSheet(conn);
            command = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + firstSheetName + "]", conn);
            command.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Table");
            dtSet = new DataSet();

            command.Fill(dtSet);
            dgvInputFile.DataSource = dtSet.Tables[0];
```

I'm using first row from excel file as column header.
I'm adding checkbox column:

```
dtSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Some header", typeof(bool)));
```

but then the header for checkbox column push the column 1 row down and the datagridview have this format.

```
Some header  |  header 1  |  header 2
--------------------------------------
checkboxcell | some value |  some value
checkboxcell | some value |  some value
checkboxcell | some value |  some value
checkboxcell <-- Unwanted checkboxcell !!!
```

How can I add checkbox column that begin from second row, or contains `dataset.Rows.Count - 1` elements?

Comment: unexpected checkbox in the last row of grid can be a result of `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property set to `true` (default). try set it to `false` for `dgvInputFile`

Comment: Thank you! You can add this as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unexpected checkbox in the last row of grid can be a result of `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property set to `true` (default), which adds new row for input

try set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` for `dgvInputFile`

by the way, when AllowUserToAddRows = true, the count of rows in grid (`dgvInputFile.RowCount`) is equal to `dataset.Rows.Count + 1`